# How to convert Type B or Type C of text in iText API

Tags: itext

I need to convert a part of a text to type B/type C using iText API, while generating the barcode. As requirment, i have 20 characters as input, out of which last 5 characters are to be converted to type B character.

Can anyone help me with code snippet.

thanks in advance.
= sapty.

Comment: What do you mean by *type B/type C*?

Comment: Few characters ( say 10 charcaters of 20 characters) of the input text has to be compressed with using  CODE_AB_TO_C. Any clue how to use this ? (ref :  http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/Barcode128.html#CODE_AB_TO_C )

Comment: Ah, I missed your *while generating the barcode* from your question. Unfortunately I have no experience with bar code creation and, therefore, cannot help. To attract more attention to your question by people knowing barcodes, you might want to make that fact more prominent, e.g. by appropriate tags.